# Devise not generating registration paths/ routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, devise

I have created a new project using devise login according to Ryan Bates' [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise?view=asciicast).
It does not have the registration routes (unlike a previous project I made, with exactly the same steps)

[This image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1145110/screenshot.png) shows the two 'rake routes' commands. The top shell is my previous project that works flawlessly and the bottom is the new project.

Is there any logical reason that it didn't create the routes properly? Can I add the routes? How do I make it *work*?

EDIT:
Here is my routes.rb file, identical to a working devise project, standard comments removed.

```
Clubadmin::Application.routes.draw do
  #added by devise
  devise_for :users
  #added by me for home page
  root :to => "home#index"
  #And I don't like RESTful apps.
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end
```

Comment: I cam not able to discern what you mean. Provide us with more information and some of your code.

Comment: It is more the operation of devise - not creating the routes, when I followed the same instructions and got a working setup. What code would be required (I am new to rails, as you've probably guessed..)

Comment: Could you post the contents of `config/routes.rb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I can't see why the version Ryan Bates uses would not work twice, but I installed devise 1.4.9 and followed the installation briefly outlined [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

To make the logout link work I had to change the path type from `:delete` to `:get` in `config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

to

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

And it has worked twice so far.

Answer (score 23):

Make sure to have in your User model the following:

```
devise :registerable
```

If not present, devise will not generate registration routes for you.

More information in [here](http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper:devise_for) and [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages)

Comment: I have; devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

Comment: If I dont have registerable, but i put it later. did a db:rollback since this was the only migration i ran, then db:migrate, rake routes did not generate the route. what other command should i give

Comment: `rails generate devise:install`
and
`rails generate devise MODEL`